# Autohotkey, how to loop the value of variable inside the value of Array

Tags: arrays, loops, variables, autohotkey

I am struggling with autohotkey's arrays and loops.

As you can see below, thanks to **"v"Array[A_Index]** part I could create two variables **app** and **adm**, which are as well values of Array 1 and Array 2.

My question is, how to Loop the value of all variables created that way?

example: variable app has value 4, variable adm has value 5, I want to loop these values using Array directives.

I was trying to do something like: 
**Loop %Array[A_Index]%** but it does not work. Any ideas?

P.S. sorry for my english, but I couldn't express it better,

```
Array := [] 
Array[1] := "app"
Array[2] := "adm"

Loop % Array.count()
{
    Gui, Add, Edit, % "v"Array[A_Index] " x30 y" NodesCount " w50 h17"
    }

Loop % Array.count()
{

    Loop Array[A_Index]
    {
    MsgBox, % A_Index
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the variable `NodesCount` needs assigned or this snippet will have an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about the purpose of what this is supposed to do, but I made all the parts work. I added a `NodesCount` variable, along with assigning values to `app` and `adm` as you mentioned in your example. I also added a `Gui, Show` since it seemed necessary. I like to use `.` to concatenate as it helps my brain understand what's going on, but that isn't required.

In the second loop, I assigned the content of the array item to a variable; I then assign the contents of the contents to the same variable. There may be a cleaner way to do this, but I didn't have success applying this directly to the array; that is, `test := %Array[A_Index]%` and `test := % Array[A_Index]` didn't work.

```
f1::
app := 4 , adm := 5 , NodesCount := 10
Array := [] , Array[1] := "app" , Array[2] := "adm"

Loop % Array.count()
    Gui, Add, Edit, % "v" . Array[A_Index] . " x30 y" . NodesCount + 20 * ( A_Index - 1 ) . " w50 h17"
Gui, Show

Loop , % Array.count()
{
    test := Array[A_Index] , test := %test%
    Loop , % test
        MsgBox, % A_Index
}
Return
```